# Integrate a mp3 player into a page with no reloading issue

Tags: html, flash

Is there any way to integrate an flash mp3 player into a html site where an reload wouldn't stop music playing or make it start from beginning.
I wouldn't want to use ajax for the rest of the site cause it's not SEO friendly, and also pop-ups are not a good solution cause every browser nowdays blocks them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AJAX can be made SEO friendly as long as you create distinct urls for the pages you are pulling in. One solution I have seen to this is to use a pop up for the player, and they are easily unblocked.

Answer (score 0):

without pop-ups, ajax, or a full flash site, there is no way to prevent this.

Answer (score 0):

You *could* have a container page that plays the MP3, and contains a 100% wide, 100% high IFRAME that embeds the actual site. However, this has numerous SEO and usability implications that you can look up under the keyword of "frames."

Answer (score 0):

You could use frames. Put the player in a frame of its own and only change the other(s). But I think a reload would still reload all the frames unless you loaded the page then redirected so that clicking the reload button in the browser only reloaded the redirected page.

You're going to jump through some hoops and have to do some things that are not SEO friendly to get this to work. If you get it to work at all.