# How to insert music in a website?

Tags: javascript, html, css, xhtml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Integrate a mp3 player into a page with no reloading issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1863366/integrate-a-mp3-player-into-a-page-with-no-reloading-issue)

I have a website of 10 webpages and I want to insert an automatic playing song in this site.

However I want that when I click on another webpage of this site then the music doesn't stop.

Is this a way to do this without using iframe or flash ?

Comment: I don't know, how this can be achived, I can only advise you to not play any music: it's simply annoying...

Comment: Here's another dupe with more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2205021/can-you-make-an-embedded-mp3-keep-playing-from-where-it-left-off

Comment: Background music on websites is *so* 1995...

Comment: Even if I must agree with both comments advising "please, don't do that", I had, once, to do such a thing. I successed by using a jquery player and a flash plugin (to read mp3) and recorded the time in a cookie, when you go to another page, the music is played back exactly where it stopped on the previous page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: I did not read your question fully. Unless you are using frames or Ajax for navigation (as in Gmail or New Twitter), this is not possible.

[Old method](http://www.webreference.com/js/column20/bgsound.html)

```
<BGSOUND SRC="aladdin.mid" LOOP=10>
```

[Or use HTML 5](http://www.w3.org/html/wiki/Elements/bgsound)

```
<audio autoplay id="bgsound">
 <source src="http://media.w3.org/2010/07/bunny/04-Death_Becomes_Fur.mp4"
         type="audio/mp4">
 <source src="http://media.w3.org/2010/07/bunny/04-Death_Becomes_Fur.oga"
         type="audio/ogg; codecs=vorbis">
 <p>Your user agent does not support the HTML5 Audio element.</p>
</audio>
<button type="button"
        onclick="document.getElementById('bgsound').pause();">
  Stop background sound
</button>

<p>
You'll probably annoy your readers if you use background sounds in documents.
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all: **don't start play music automatically on a webpage**, let the user decide about to start the music or not.

You should put all your webpages into a long webpage, each one into a DIV:

```
<div id="page1">
 content of page 1
</div>
<div id="page2" style="display: hidden">
 content of page 2
</div>
<!-- etc. -->
```

Except the first one, hide the divs by CSS or style tag, see example. Then all the links pointing to other pages should call a small javascript code, which changes the visibility of the divs, turning the "referenced" one visible and hide others:

```
<a href="#" onclick="switchToPage(2)"> go to page 2 </a>
```

The player should be placed before the divs, or anywhere. The advantage of this method, that you may make a fix footer, header etc., and change only the content area. The disadvantage is that search engines will only see a long page instead of 10.

But again: **don't make a webpage which starts playing music automatically!**